# How to Access Drive out of root drive in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any solution to load local resources in web browsers.
I'm trying to load a video dynamically in my php script. The root folder of script is C:/path/to/root and video is stored at D:/path/to/video.
I tried

```
<video controls autoplay>
<source src="file:///D:/vid/mov/<?php echo "$link";?>" type="video/mp4"> 
<source src="file:///D:/vid/mov/<?php echo "$link";?>" type="video/ogg" />
</video>
```

but that didn't work.
Any Solution??
Please Note - This is a constraint that I have to load video from a separate path out of the root drive.

Thank you !!﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue will be that as PHP is living inside your web server it SHOULD only access web accessible locations.

The easiest option is probbaly to create a new webshare that uses the location of the D drive and access it usign the new webshares URI.